# Command to read/import .dbf files from local system into SQL Server 2016 64 bit

Tags: sql-server-2016, linked-server, dbf, dbase, openrowset

I am trying to import `.dbf` files into SQL Server 2016 64bit. For this I installed Microsoft Visual FoxPro. Below setup works for 32bit version of SQL Server but not to 64bit. I also tried changing the driver's name eg: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0, etc. but no luck.

```
USE [master] 
GO 

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

USE [master] 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'VFPOLEDB', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO
```

And then,

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(200),
        @path AS NVARCHAR(200),
        @table AS NVARCHAR(200)

SET @path = 'C:\Users\sid\Downloads\VPF\'
SET @table = 'dmfiles'
SET @sql = 'Select * from openrowset(''VFPOLEDB'','''+@path+''';'''';'''',''select * from '+@table+'.dbf'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Also tried creating a Linked server type of cmd:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET ('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','dBase 
5.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=\Dbf Directory\','SELECT * FROM dbf_filename.dbf')
```

When I either try to open Linked server, run any command, SQL Server just says executing and never shows any result nor throws error.

I tried using DBF Viewer 2000 to convert `.dbf` to `.sql` and ran them against a DB but, running above SQL (if worked fine) would be great for my automation script.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: First Question:  Is this a one-time conversion or something that needs to support on-going data exchanges?

Comment: VFP only supports 32-bit operations regardless of the OS.   If this is a one-time operation, have you considered using the VFP tool - Upsizing Wizard?  Do a Google Search for:   vfp upsizing wizard

Comment: @Dhugalmac, I will be using it for an on-going data exchanges. I shall put this cmd into a PowerShell script and will be running either manual or will schedule it.

Comment: Since doing for ongoing, you would probably be best to PUSH the data from VFP UP to SQL, even if it is into a temporary set of storage tables, then PULL from SQL process that may require additional validations to your app requirements.